# how to install iPhone sdk 3 and iPhone sdk 4 on same mac

Tags: iphone

I need to install iPhone sdk 3 and iPhone sdk 4 on same mac, for testing purposes because some of my iPhone sdk 3 project are not working on iPhone sdk 4.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing them, specify custom (not default) location for them.